# prove that a language is context free given a regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, closure-properties

R is a regular language over $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$
$Sub(R)=\{0^i1^j \mid \exists w\in R.|w|=i-j \}$
I need to prove that Sub(R) is context free.

I know that the [quotient of a context free language with a regular language is context free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_quotient)
but I can't seem to continue for there..

Comment: What specifically is your problem continuing from there? See [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18524/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-context-free/) and quite a few questions about [tag:context-free+closure-properties] for inspiration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi(R) \subseteq 0^*$ result from $R$ by substituting $0$ for $1$. Alternatively, $\phi(R) = \{ 0^{|w|} : w \in R \}$. The previous description makes it clear that $\phi(R)$ is also regular. Now
$$
\operatorname{Sub}(R) = \phi(R) \{ 0^j 1^j \},
$$
the concatenation of the regular language $\phi(R)$ and the context-free language $\{0^j 1^j\}$.